# How to map a component with different array's item

Tags: javascript, reactjs

how to explain this I don't know but this is my nightmare. If I learn how to do this, it will be very important for me. I want to map a component and this component uses like `<Flag.USA/>` or `<Flag.RU/>`. I have an array like this: `["TR","USA","RU"]`. I want to map this component with items of that array.

So, at the end, I want to see something like this:

```
<Flag.TR/>
<Flag.USA/>
<Flag.RU/>
```

Here is my code, but it's not working:

```
const languages = ["TR", "USA", "RU"]
{
    languages.map((language, i) => {
        <Flags.{language}/> //Here is very importat... I tried like this but didn't work.
    })
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Flags is a component of a package. `country-flag-icons`. If you want to use it, you can use like `<Flags.USA/>` and there will be USA flag.

Comment: What is `Flags` variable?

Comment: You don't really want lots of different flag components. You want one that you pass props into.

Comment: Hello, you can do as suggested here https://medium.com/@Carmichaelize/dynamic-tag-names-in-react-and-jsx-17e366a684e9.
I don't think that you can use a composed name for components. (meaning Flag.Something is not allowed).
I suggest you to read best practices concerning component naming in ReactJS (check it here https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html).

Answer (score 0):

Syntax `<Flags.{language}/>` is not allowed in jsx.
You can use `createElement` here
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement

```
languages.map((language, i) => {
    return React.createElement(Flags[language])
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a list of language objects including the exact name of the component, if you want to have a short list:

```
const languages = [
    {key: "TR", comp: <Flag.TR />}, 
    {key: "USA", comp: <Flag.USA />}, 
    {key: "RU", comp: <Flag.RU />},
]
```

And then, you can loop:

```
languages.map((language, i) => {
    return language.comp
})
```